# $M[x_1,...,x_n]\cong M\otimes_RR[x_1,...,x_n]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, tensor-products

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with 1, $M$ an $R$-module. I know $M[x]\cong M\otimes_RR[x]$. Is it true that we can extend this to the more general case, i.e., $M[x_1,...,x_n]\cong M\otimes_RR[x_1,...,x_n]$?

Comment: Hint: What is $R[x]\otimes_R R[y]$?

Comment: Thank you very much! So for example, $M\otimes_RR[x,y]\cong M\otimes_RR[x]\otimes_RR[y]\cong M[x]\otimes_RR[y]\cong M[x,y]$.